# JSON API response.body only providing one row of response

Tags: json

I want to Create a shortcut `@CustomerIDs` from a GET response body that looks like this:

```json
[
  {
    "Id": "23"
  },
  {
    "Id": "71"
  },
  {
    "Id": "116"
  },
  {
    "Id": "197"
  },
]
```

I have made the following row:

```
@CustomerIDs='{{customers.response.body.$.[Id]}}
```

I need all IDs to be included in the `@CustomerIDs`.
The current results just show 23, i.e. the first ID answer, and none of the following.

Let me know if I need to clarify more, I am not an experienced programmer at all.

Comment: You would want to add more information to your question, like the actual code snippet performing the GET request and a sample of the request response output. However, to achieve what you want you need to create a new array by for looping over the response output and only appending the Id value to your new array.